# My Social icons are pushing my logo away from the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I am building a responsive website using Bootstrap and Less.

I have put in some social Icons using font awesome which have worked fine.

However, my logo in meant to be in the center and was before I put the social icons in but now I have added them they are pushing my logo to the left.

Here is the html

```
<header> 
    <div id="social"> 
        <ul class="pull-right"> 
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="https://twitter.com/mytwitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
 <div class = "logomove">
    <div id="logo" class="text-center">
        <a href="/"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
    </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

And the CSS:

```
#social {
li {list-style: none; display: inline-block; padding:3px; float:right; color:@brand-primary; } 
 }
```

I have also tried positioning the logo 250px across the page to try and center it but it will not work.

Any suggestions much appreciated, I'm really new to this so sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: do you have some jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The static positioning of your `#social` element is pushing the logo away. You have to make either of them absolute to make it not effect the other element.

Try like this:

```
header{
    position:relative;
}
#social {
    li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding:3px;
        float:right;
        color:@brand-primary;
        position:absolute;
        right:0px;
        top:0px;
    } 
}
```

You might need to adjust the `top` and `right` values.